# How to set the configuration for running MR job in CDH5 Hue?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, hue

I have successfully installed and initiated the CDH5 and when I am trying to run a simple WordCount example via Hue, I am facing the following error.

```
2015-05-13 12:58:04,374 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[localhost] USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[trialWC] JOB[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-05-13 12:58:04,375 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[localhost] USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[trialWC] JOB[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2015-05-13 12:58:04,375 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[localhost] USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[trialWC] JOB[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2015-05-13 12:58:04,477 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[localhost] USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[trialWC] JOB[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@java-d1fb] Start action [0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@java-d1fb] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2015-05-13 12:58:05,745 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[localhost] USER[hdfs] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[trialWC] JOB[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-150513124629466-oozie-oozi-W@java-d1fb] Error starting action [java-d1fb]. ErrorType [TRANSIENT], ErrorCode [JA009], Message [JA009: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=1536, maxMemory=1024
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)
]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA009: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=1536, maxMemory=1024
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:456)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:440)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1162)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:234)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:286)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:321)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=1536, maxMemory=1024
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:559)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:550)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:993)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=1536, maxMemory=1024
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.submitApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.submitApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.submitApplication(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:290)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException): Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=1536, maxMemory=1024
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.validateAndCreateResourceRequest(RMAppManager.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.createAndPopulateNewRMApp(RMAppManager.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager.submitApplication(RMAppManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ClientRMService.submitApplication(ClientRMService.java:574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationClientProtocol$ApplicationClientProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationClientProtocol.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.submitApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.submitApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:232)
    ... 35 more
```

PS: I have set the Container Memory Maximum (yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb) to 2GB, with no help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully found the configuration that needs to be changed.
It is the **Container Memory** (`yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`). I set it to 2GB, sufficient for my current usage. Other configurations can also be tried out, keeping in mind that it should not exceed the maximum memory!